# How to return JSON data with angular from a java servlet?

Tags: java, json, angularjs

The main goal is to return some JSON data with Angular from a Java servlet.
So, I have a factory `DispatcherService` where I'm getting my resource key:

`cfdb.tasks.primite.list=/task/received_task.do?method=list&cleanSess=1&json=true`

In my Chrome console I get this:

```
tasks data Resource { SESSION_ATTRIBUTES: Object, REQUEST_PARAMETERS: Object,
REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES: Object, $promise: Promise, $resolved: true} $promise: Promise$resolved: true REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES: Object REQUEST_PARAMETERS: ObjectSESSION_ATTRIBUTES: Object__proto__: Resource
tasksCtrl.js:42
```

But I don't know why I can`t access objects from my JSON.

```
.factory('DispatcherService', ['$resource', '$location', 'UrlService', function ($resource, $location, UrlService) {
    var contextPath = UrlService.getContextPath();

    return $resource('', {}, {
        getResource: {url: contextPath + '/rest/dispatch', method: 'GET', isArray: false},
        getArray: {url: contextPath + '/rest/dispatch', method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        invalidateSession: {url: contextPath + '/rest/invalidate/session', method: 'GET', isArray: false},
        downloadFile: {url: contextPath + '/rest/download/file', method: 'GET', isArray: false},
        postResource: {url: contextPath + '/rest/dispatch', method: 'POST', isArray: false}
    });
}])

.controller('TasksCtrl', ['$scope', 'DispatcherService', 'HideHeadersService', '$location', '$log', '$http',
function ($scope, DispatcherService, HideHeadersService, $location, $log, $http) {

DispatcherService.getResource({
  key: 'cfdb.tasks.primite.list'

}, function success(data) {
  $scope.todos = data; //edited
  $log.debug("tasks data",data);
  console.log("break and my code: ");

}, function error(data) {
  // $scope.pagination.loading = false;
  $log.debug("ERROR - getTabResource", data.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES);
  if (data.status && data.status == 401)
    $location.path("/login");
});
}])
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TasksCtrl">
   <p ng-repeat="task in todos track by $index">{{task.receivedTasksList}}</p> //edited
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure that your JsonObject is really a JSON Object and not a String? did you tried to parse it before using it?

Comment: I used extension rest for chrome, and in the JSON tab I can see all the objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I see I bounded my `$scope` with the debug message for no reason: `$scope.todos = $log.debug("tasks data",data);`

Solution:

```
1) $scope.todos = data;
2) <p ng-repeat="task in todos track by $index">{{task.receivedTasksList}}</p>
```